Need a efficient workflow for creating shoulder topology for a humanoid to be animated
I am trying to create a character model to be used in animation.
The issue is I need a efficient method/workflow to create a shoulder with the topology in the below picture (Circled in Blue).
Update
But in a T Pose
Its just really tricky trying to make this shoulder in this way

Now here is a another angle of my humanoid model to you lot help out.


What do you mean by "efficient workflow"? --- You can replicate the model in A-pose, add an armature and change the rest pose to T-pose, can't you?

efficient workflow definition " a smooth and effective process that allows 3D Artists to complete tasks quickly and with minimal errors or delays"
